# Flutter Firebase Auth Emulator not working for firebase auth version 1.01

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-tools

I get this error, `the method 'useEmulator' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'` when trying to set up an emulator connection using `_auth = await FirebaseAuth.instance.useEmulator('http://localhost:9099');` . In the docs, including the package's example on pub.dev, this useEmulator method does exist. Was it removed in the newer versions and not documented? If so, is there a new implementation for me to use. I'm using Flutter 2.0.0 stable and firebase_core: ^1.0.2 firebase_auth: ^1.0.1 without null safety. Thanks.

EDIT

---

I was running on a cached version of my dependencies which was not picking firebase_core: ^1.0.2 firebase_auth: ^1.0.1. These versions support useEmulator.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Firebase did you use? iOS, Android or Web?

Try to upgrade to last version of Firebase, the `useEmulator` feature is pretty new.

Comment: Thanks. Noticed I was using a cached version of my dependencies. So I was using an older version of the dependencies. Ran a ` flutter clean ` and it works now.

Comment: Yes, good practice a little `flutter clean` sometimes 